# Opening and using Safari

Tags: python, macos

I am relatively new to the mac world.  My question concerns opening an application using python on mac osx.  From what I've found so far, it seems as if applications are stored in app format that are actually directories.  Are these parsed somehow by the OS when opening the app?  I would like to open Safari using python and it is in my /Applications/Safari.app directory.  Is there a specific binary I should be passing to os.system or should I be going about it in a completely different way?  My end goal is to have safari open a local html file, close it then open another local html file.

Thanks,
-John

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The Python standard library includes the [webbrowser](http://docs.python.org/library/webbrowser.html) module which allows you to open a new browser window or tab in a platform-independent way.  It does support Safari on OS X if it is the user's default:

```
>>> import webbrowser
>>> webbrowser.open("http://stackoverflow.com")
```

But `webbrowser` does not support closing a browser window.  For that level of control, you are best off using Safari's Apple Event scripting interface by installing [py-appscript](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/appscript/).

```
>>> from appscript import *
>>> safari = app("Safari")
>>> safari.make(new=k.document,with_properties={k.URL:"http://stackoverflow.com"})
>>> safari.windows.first.current_tab.close()
```

If you just want to change the web page displayed in the tab you opened:

```
>>> safari.windows.first.current_tab.URL.set("http://www.google.com")
>>> safari.windows.first.current_tab.URL.set("http://www.python.com")
```

Safari's Apple Events interface is somewhat non-intuitive (unfortunately, that's not unusual with Mac applications).  There are references out there if you need to do more complex stuff.  But Python and py-appscript give you a solid base to work from.

Comment: Thanks for the answer that works for any browser and OS. Before I scrolled down to the answers, I thought the answers would just be using os.system or subprocess.Popen. Instead, you gave us an ingenious answer.

Comment: Any idea why this may open Firefox by default, even though Safari is the system's default browser? I can't use browser `type` `'macosx'`, but at least `webbrowser.get('safari')` works as discussed in the documentation.

Answer (score 4):

os.system("open -a /Applications/Safari.app http://www.google.com")
for this to work when safari is not the default add -a after open.
Cant comment yet (reputation below 50 (: )

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
os.system("open /Applications/Safari.app http://www.google.com")
```

Comment: Thanks that works.  Would there be a way to interact with safari in terms of closing individual tabs or webpages it has open?

Comment: @user583599 Interacting with Safari is best done with Apple events. See @Ned's answer.

Comment: From looking at Ned's answer and from some searching I came up with http://wiki.python.org/moin/MacPython/AppscriptModule for anyone interested.

Comment: I hope you did see the link I provided to the py-appscript download page which includes the link to the project page which contains full documentation on py-appscript.